# ¿Cómo desmarco este checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un script que no puedo hacer funcionar.

Este es el `HTML`:

```
<div class="well">
  <h2>Select you files</h2>
  <table id="list-files" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="10px"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all-files" checked="checked"></th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Size</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="0" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[0]" value="tuSITIO.com.txt"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>34.0 iB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="1" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[1]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.mkv"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>8.8 GiB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="2" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[2]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.nfo"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>5.4 KiB</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

La idea es **desmarcar** la casilla de verificación usando `jquery` del archivo **tuSITIO.com.txt** intenté hacerlo con `$("input:checkbox[value=1]").removeAttr("checked");` este funciona pero a menudo **tuSITIO.com.txt** aparece en otras posiciones aleatoriamente y como notarán este desmarca como única opción la segunda casilla..
Entonces necesito uno que **desmarque tuSITIO.com.txt** en donde sea que se encuentre :D

Mi `script`:

```
$("#uncheck-id").on("click", function(){
    let tuSitioCheckbox = $("#tusitiocheckbox");
    tuSitioCheckbox.prop("checked", !tuSitioCheckbox.prop("checked"));
});
```

Este `script` lo hizo [Marcos Martínez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4163/marcos-mart%C3%ADnez) y me dijo explicó que

> asumiendo que no hay garantía que el checkbox se encuentre en la
>   segunda posición una opcion sería esta: (la que pone arriba)

El problema es que no puedo hacer funcionar ese `script`! Coloco el `HTML` mas el `script` en http://jsfiddle.net/ y no funciona, ni menos en el sitio donde lo quiero aplicar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacer esto:

```js
var inp=$("tr input");
var r="tuSITIO.com.txt";
for (i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) { 
 if(inp[i].value == r){
  inp[i-1].checked = false;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well">
  <h2>Select you files</h2>
  <table id="list-files" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="10px"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all-files" checked="checked"></th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Size</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="0" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[0]" value="tuSITIO.com.txt" checked></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>34.0 iB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="1" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[1]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.mkv"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>8.8 GiB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="2" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[2]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.nfo"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>5.4 KiB</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No puedo hacer que funcione.. coloco el `script` y lo corro http://jsfiddle.net/ pero sigue sin desmarcarse :'(

el `script` lo pongo en Tampermonkey, es para el sitio https://multiup.org/en/upload/from-torrent donde coloco un archivo .torrent luego salen esos datos q coloco en el 'HTML' por supuesto para probar el 'script' lo ejecuto "simuladamente" en jsfiddle.net pero sin resultados.

Claro que luego de funcionar el codigo tengo la tarea de hacer que corra DESPUÉS de que carguen los datos con alguna '$(function()' preferentemente de las que ejecutan luego de determinado evento

Comment: @Stack_qwerty ya se hizo la modificacion fue un peque;o error de mi parte sorry!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo funciona de maravilla! mi me permitís te hago un par de consultas; como haría para incluir otro elemento a desmarcar por ej: "tuSITIO.com.txt", "tuWEB.net.txt", "tuCASA.in.txt" en el mismo código? si no es posible no tengo problema con duplicar el código con los elementos cambiados.

Comment: Y la ultima.. como ´podria hacer para que ese código que me pasaste se ejecuté luego de que se genere esa lista donde aparece "tuSITIO.com.txt"? hay un código 'jquery' que permite corre el 'script' luego de un evento o función, que bien podría ser tomado de los que aparecen luego de cargar los datos donde surge tuSITIO.com.txt. si no podés ayudarme en esta de todos modos fue valiosísimo tu aporte muchas gracias, saludos!